# access comparator of container (C++/STL)

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I have a vector of min priority queues, each one created with different instance of custom comparator class. Queues are supposed to be limited in size, and in case the queue is full, only element with higher priority than top of the queue can be inserted and kick out the element on top. So before inserting into full queue I want to compare new element against the top of the queue using the queues' own comparator to avoid the insertion/deletion cost. Is that possible to do without recreating the comparator?

Edit:
@Kerrek's hack is really cool but the comparators do have to be created by constructor with parameter, I should've mentioned that. So I went with @Spundun answer, also I used access to underlying container for faster printing.

Comment: You mean `container<YourClass>::key_compare()` ? And it makes no sense  in `std::queue<>` anyway, I think you mean `std::priority_queue<>` don't you ?

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah, its a member in most instances I've seen (`comp`) and I think you're right, at least I've never seen it public and I don't think the standard calls for it to be so anyway. edit: just checked, it in the standard as protected.

Comment: Yeah, @WhozCraig, you are right, it is a `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: I thought it might be. Ultimately you provide the predicate yourself anyway (unless you're relying on the default `std::less<>`, so I'm not entirely clear what the gain is, but I'm sure you have your reasons for wanting it =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the comparator is a protected member(named comp, +1 Nate). So if you derive your own priority queue class from the stl class, and implement the functionality you described as a function (say insert_only_if_important() ) then you can access the comparator from within that function.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the comparator object is not exposed by `std::priority_queue`, not even its type. As a dirty hack, and under the assumption that the comparator is stateless and default-constructible, you could attempt something like this:

```
template <typename> struct kidnap_comparator;

template <typename T, typename Cnt, typename Cmp>
struct kidnap_comparator<std::priority_queue<T, Cnt, Cmp>>
{
    typedef Cmp type;
};


// ...

template <typename PQ>
void insert_maybe(PQ & pq, typename PQ::const_reference x)
{
    typename kidnap_comparator<PQ>::type cmp;

    // use "cmp" to compare pq.top() and x
}
```

Comment: This will "create" a new comparator. I donno if that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: In C++11 you could also use a `reference_wrapper` around the comparator to keep a reference to it.

Comment: @pmr: How would that help?

Comment: It wont. I misread the question. OP needs a generic way to access the comparator. I missed that.